# Why am I getting "is out of scope" from JSLint for a function called from an event?

Tags: javascript, jslint

I need to reinitialize the state of some html elements from two different events (an html select change and a checkbox change), so I created a function that I placed outside the "ready" function to do that, and call it from both events.

However, JSLint flags this call to it:

```
$('#unitsselect').change(function() {
    unitSelected = true;

    reinitializeRecipientsAndGenerateVals();
    . . .
```

...as being "out of scope"; specifically, it tells me,

> 'reinitializeRecipientsAndGenerateVals' is out of scope.

and indicates that line as the problematic one.

`reinitializeRecipientsAndGenerateVals()` is indeed outside that change event handler, and also outside the "ready" function. I put it inside the ready function to see if that was the problem, but I still get that warning from JSLint with it there.

How can I reuse this function so that I don't have to move it inside both change event handlers?

Note: [This](https://jslinterrors.com/) has an "used out of scope" section, but not an "is out of scope"

According to [this](https://jslinterrors.com/a-used-out-of-scope), all versions of JSLint use "{a} used outside of binding context"

### UPDATE

Even when I move the function right *into* the change event handler, JSLint complains in the same way.

### UDPATE 2

For Travis, here is the whole enchilada:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var unitSelected = false;
    var checkboxSelected = false;

    // When unit is selected, populate the data range value elements; if checkbox selected,
    // also populate email recipients and generate vals (specific day or based on a pattern)
    $('#unitsselect').change(function() {
        unitSelected = true;

        reinitializeRecipientsAndGenerateVals();

        var unitval = $('#unitsselect').val();
        // This is admittedly kludgy - copying the same ajax call multiple times, changing only
        // the report number; but a forloop attempt failed because of the asynchronous nature of
        // it all; for some reason, populatedatarangeprams() was called only once, and with a
        // rptval of 5 (when it "should have been" 1..4 instead).
        var model = JSON.stringify({ unit: unitval, report: 1 });
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '@Url.Action("GetUnitDataRangeParamsVals", "UnitReportDataRangeParams")',
            data: { unit: unitval, report: 1 },
            contentType: 'application/json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(returneddata) {
                populatedatarangeprams(1, returneddata);
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('error - returneddata.error.stringify');
            }
        });

        model = JSON.stringify({ unit: unitval, report: 2 });
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '@Url.Action("GetUnitDataRangeParamsVals", "UnitReportDataRangeParams")',
            data: { unit: unitval, report: 2 },
            contentType: 'application/json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(returneddata) {
                populatedatarangeprams(2, returneddata);
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('error - returneddata.error.stringify');
            }
        });

        model = JSON.stringify({ unit: unitval, report: 3 });
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '@Url.Action("GetUnitDataRangeParamsVals", "UnitReportDataRangeParams")',
            data: { unit: unitval, report: 3 },
            contentType: 'application/json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(returneddata) {
                populatedatarangeprams(3, returneddata);
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('error - returneddata.error.stringify');
            }
        });

        model = JSON.stringify({ unit: unitval, report: 4 });
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '@Url.Action("GetUnitDataRangeParamsVals", "UnitReportDataRangeParams")',
            data: { unit: unitval, report: 4 },
            contentType: 'application/json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(returneddata) {
                populatedatarangeprams(4, returneddata);
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('error - returneddata.error.stringify');
            }
        });

        if (!checkboxSelected) {
            return;
        }

        // from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36870365/how-can-i-elegantize-this-verbose-jquery/
        rptval = $('[id^=ckbx_]').filter(':checked').val();
        setEmailAndGenerateValsForUnitReportPair(unitval, rptval);
    }); // $('#unitsselect').change(function ()

    // Checkbox selection has changed; if Unit has been selected, populate the email and generate vals
    $(".ckbx").change(function() {
        if (!this.checked) {
            checkboxSelected = false;
            reinitializeRecipientsAndGenerateVals();
            return;
        }

        checkboxSelected = true;
        // this unchecks all other checkboxes (from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17785010/jquery-uncheck-other-checkbox-on-one-checked):
        $('.ckbx').not(this).prop('checked', false);
        reinitializeRecipientsAndGenerateVals();

        // If no unit is selected, vals can not be set, so exit now
        if (!unitSelected) {
            return;
        }

        var unitval = $('#unitsselect').val();
        var rptval = $(this).val();
        setEmailAndGenerateValsForUnitReportPair(unitval, rptval);
    }); // $(".ckbx").change(function ()

}); // "ready" function

    function setEmailAndGenerateValsForUnitReportPair(unitval, rptval) {
        var model = JSON.stringify({ unit: unitval, report: rptval });
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '@Url.Action("GetUnitReportPairEmailAddresses", "UnitReportPair")',
            data: { unit: unitval, report: rptval },
            contentType: 'application/json', //<= this is paired with stringify above; if comment out one, comment out both
            cache: false,
            success: function(returneddata) {
                populateemails(returneddata);
            },
            error: function() {
                alert(returneddata.error.stringify);
            }
        });

        // The above AJAX call retrieved email addr vals; the next one is for the "Generate and Email Report" section of the page
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '@Url.Action("GetUnitReportPairGenerateVals", "UnitReportPairGenerateVals")',
            data: { unit: unitval, report: rptval },
            contentType: 'application/json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(returneddata) {
                populategeneratevals(returneddata);
            },
            error: function() {
                alert(returneddata.error.stringify);
            }
        });
    }

    //Adapted from Jakes's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204250/check-if-checkbox-is-checked-with-jquery
    function isCheckedById(id) {
        var checked = $("input[id=" + id + "]:checked").length;
        return (checked != 0);
    }

    function populateemails(trampdata) {
        // first, clear them all
        $("#email1").val('');
        $("#email2").val('');
        $("#email3").val('');
        // Now set those for which there are values
        if (trampdata.UnitReportPairEmailVals.length > 0) {
            $("#email1").val(trampdata.UnitReportPairEmailVals[0]);
        }
        if (trampdata.UnitReportPairEmailVals.length > 1) {
            $("#email2").val(trampdata.UnitReportPairEmailVals[1]);
        }
        if (trampdata.UnitReportPairEmailVals.length > 2) {
            $("#email3").val(trampdata.UnitReportPairEmailVals[2]);
        }
    }

    function populategeneratevals(generateddata) {
        // first, clear them all, if they had been set to something else
        $("#dayofmonthselect").val('1st');
        $("#ordinalselect").val('First');
        $("#dayofweekselect").val('Monday');
        $("#weekormonthselect").val('Month');

        // Now set those for which there are values
        var domOrdinalified = ordinalify(generateddata.generatevals.DayOfMonth);
        $("#dayofmonthselect").val(domOrdinalified);
        $("#ordinalselect").val(generateddata.generatevals.PatternOrdinal);
        $("#dayofweekselect").val(generateddata.generatevals.PatternDOW);
        $("#weekormonthselect").val(generateddata.generatevals.PatternInterval);

        // Now set the correct radio button
        if ($("#dayofmonthselect").val() === 0) {
            $("#groupRptGenerationAndSendingByDayOfMonth").prop("checked", true);
        } else {
            $("#groupRptGenerationAndSendingBasedOnAPattern").prop("checked", true);
        }
    }

    function ordinalify(domint) {
        if (domint === 1 || domint === 21 || domint === 31) {
            return domint + 'st';
        }
        if (domint === 2 || domint === 22) {
            return domint + 'nd';
        }
        if (domint === 3 || domint === 23) {
            return domint + 'rd';
        }
        return domint + 'th';
    }

    function populatedatarangeprams(rptval, returneddata) {
        if (rptval === 1) {
            // Produce Usage
            $("#produsagefrom").val(returneddata.datarangeparams.TimeUnitsFrom);
            $("#produsageto").val(returneddata.datarangeparams.TimeUnitsTo);
        } else if (rptval === 2) {
            // Delivery Performance
            $("#delperffrom").val(returneddata.datarangeparams.TimeUnitsFrom);
            $("#delperfto").val(returneddata.datarangeparams.TimeUnitsTo);
        } else if (rptval === 3) {
            // Price Compliance
            $("#pricecompliancefrom").val(returneddata.datarangeparams.TimeUnitsFrom);
            $("#pricecomplianceto").val(returneddata.datarangeparams.TimeUnitsTo);
        } else if (rptval === 4) {
            // Fill Rate
            $("#fillratefrom").val(returneddata.datarangeparams.TimeUnitsFrom);
            $("#fillrateto").val(returneddata.datarangeparams.TimeUnitsTo);
        }
        // TODO: Add 5 if/when Contract vs Market is added
    }

    function reinitializeRecipientsAndGenerateVals() {
        $("#email1").val('');
        $("#email2").val('');
        $("#email3").val('');

        $("#dayofmonthselect").val('1st');
        $("#ordinalselect").val('First');
        $("#dayofweekselect").val('Monday');
        $("#weekormonthselect").val('Month');
    }
```

Comment: Is the `reinit...` a property of the `window` object? If so, you could probably get rid of the complaint if you call it as `window.reinitNameTooLong()`.

Comment: "All down but nine; set 'em up on the other alley, pard." (I don't know what you mean by "a member of the window object")

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JsLint 'out of scope' error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485171/jslint-out-of-scope-error)

Comment: Sorry, I meant a /property/ of the window object.

Comment: I'm having trouble replicating the error. Can you give us something we can copy & paste directly into www.jslint.com that will throw the error you are describing?

Comment: @amphetamachine: Yeah, it's the "window object" that I don't understand. This is all just jquery within a "<script type="text/javascript">" section in a "@section Scripts" in a .cshtml file in an ASP.NET MVC project.

Comment: @Travis: Okay, I'll copy the whole shebang to Update 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I've tracked it down to this:

```
foo(); // <- function call

function foo() { // <- function declaration
}
```

Seem like it's an obscure way to say "Declare function before calling it!" or "Do not rely on hoisting!".

You can fix it by moving function declaration to the top.

Comment: How does the (pre)declaration differ from calling it?...JSLint still complains the same way with the function declared below "var checkboxSelected = false;"

Comment: I've pasted the updated code to http://www.jslint.com and it works just fine. Are You sure it's not complaining about another function?

Comment: I get a million "undeclared" and "out of scope" and "Expected" (especially "use strict") and "Unexpected"

I have the following in "Global variables...": $ = jQuery

...and checked "this" and "whitespace mess" in "Tolerate..." but still get a googleplex of fingerwags from the Lintometer.

HOWEVER, it is now working; how/why, I don't know (what changed)?

Comment: Though it may sound pretty lame, it is a good time investement to fix all these little beasts.

Comment: Yeah, I wish there was something I could use from Visual Studio that would flag the truly "bad" things.

Comment: If You are free to chose a linting tool, I would suggest to look at [ESLint](http://eslint.org). It's highly configurable, so you won't be distracted by minor and opinionated stuff. It is also recommended by [VS](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript#_javascript-linters-eslint-jshint).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function parameter `reinit` and bind it later on to `reinitializeRecipientsAndGenerateVals` (the function you want to reuse).

```
var onChange = (function(reinit) {
   unitSelected = true;
   reinit();
   ...
}).bind(null, reinitializeRecipientsAndGenerateVals)

$('#unitsselect').change(onChange)
```